# How to filter on geography data in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis

I am in need to filter my BigQuery table based on column which is of type Geography. I tried below queries `SELECT * FROM bigqueryproject1-279667.mycreatedataset1.newTabelwithAllDatatype where location = ST_GEOGPOINT(-6, 6)` but this shows me validation error Equality is not defined for arguments of type GEOGRAPHY . If I replcae  '=' with like operator I get message stating like is applicable only for String and Byte. I refereed [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions) documentation but not getting how to have filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(location, ST_GEOGPOINT(-6, 6))
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, that works , thanks. I see this method ST_INTERSECTS in the documentation link that i shared but was not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

For geography, equality operator is not defined.

You can use `ST_Equals`, like `ST_Equals(location,  ST_GEOGPOINT(-6, 6))` if you really want only rows with geography value (almost) exactly equal to this point.

More often you would want to filter on other conditions, e.g. intersections with specific point, use `ST_Intersects(location,  ST_GEOGPOINT(-6, 6))` or on condition of being within some distance of a point, use `ST_DWithin(location,  ST_GEOGPOINT(-6, 6), 100)` where last argument is distance in meters.